# Zero graphic card fan speed when no calculations are performed

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I have fresh install of ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and CUDA 5.5 with nvidia-331.20 driver. There are 4 GeForce GTX 780 on board. X runs on integrated card, while Nvidia cards are superposed to do some calculations.

I have noticed that 3rd card fan spin is 0 when no calculations are performed on it in spite of the temperature:

**When some calculations:**

```
    +------------------------------------------------------+                       
    | NVIDIA-SMI 331.20     Driver Version: 331.20         |                       
    |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
    | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
    |===============================+======================+======================|
    |   0  GeForce GTX 780     Off  | 0000:02:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
    | 46%   80C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     93MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    |   1  GeForce GTX 780     Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
    | 47%   80C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     93MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    |   2  GeForce GTX 780     Off  | 0000:83:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
    | 43%   79C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     93MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    |   3  GeForce GTX 780     Off  | 0000:84:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
    | 48%   80C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     93MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

**Right after termination of calculations:**

```
    +------------------------------------------------------+                       
    | NVIDIA-SMI 331.20     Driver Version: 331.20         |                       
    |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
    | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
    |===============================+======================+======================|
    |   0  GeForce GTX 780     Off  | 0000:02:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
    | 38%   73C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     10MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    |   1  GeForce GTX 780     Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
    | 38%   73C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     10MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    |   2  GeForce GTX 780     Off  | 0000:83:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
    | 38%   73C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     10MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    |   3  GeForce GTX 780     Off  | 0000:84:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
    |  0%   75C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     10MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

What could cause one of cards fan act this way?

Comment: Does the temperature go down after it is idle for a few minutes?

Comment: Yes, it does. Slower than others but goes. I think it's not really dangerous, but it seems to be strange behaviour.

Comment: Then what is strange about it?  If it isn't in use, it powers down, doesn't generate heat, and so doesn't need the fan.

Comment: Then why this scheme is not applied to the other GPUs?

Comment: I also have this problem, if you solved, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's been year since I started massive simulations on GPU under described conditions. No failure/overheat for the whole year. It seems more like aesthetic issue)